# Symfony 2.8: How do I completely turn off caching?

Tags: symfony

so we were load testing our server (thus my Symfony page last Friday) and it somehow filled up the app/cache folder.

I've some various discussions on the topic and I modified my config/file

**config.yml**

```
twig:
    cache: false
```

app_dev.php (commented out the line below)

```
//$kernel->loadClassCache();
```

Is there a way to completely turn off caching? The only workaround I can think of at the moment is to run:

```
php app/console cache:clear
```

via cron.

Thanks

Comment: As far as I know you can't. What you could probably do to get the same effect is implement getCacheDir() inside your AppKernel and return something like /dev/null - that way Symfony can write to the cache all it wants and the OS just throws the data away. (Note: this assumes you use a *nix based OS.)

Comment: different question: why would you want to do that? Caching is an integral part of symfony. it generates php out of all your configs and annotations. Otherwise it will generate everything on runtime which is incredibly slow.

Comment: @Koalabaerchen I believe I stated my reasons already. :) in any case, it was symfony profiler that's filling up the disks. I turned that off.

Comment: @mrjayviper that's not how you load test a server or an application. Also the profiler shouldn't run in the 'prod' environment in the first place.